# Why isn't MessageBox TopMost?

Tags: c#, messagebox, topmost

I recently found out that by default MessageBoxes were not the top most form when displayed by default and I was wondering if anyone knew any circumstances when you wouldn't want the messagebox to be shown on top of other windows?

I found the issue when I started to show splash screens whilst loading an application, and it looked like my program was still running but there was a `MessageBox` behind the splash screen that was waiting for input.. The splash screen was shown on a different thread to the thread that called the messagebox so I imagine this is why it didn't appear above the splash; but this still doesn't explain why MessageBox doesn't have the `MB_TOPMOST` flag by default?

**Edit**

To better clarify:
in the end I had to do something similar to this in the end to make a messagebox, code isn't exactly correct as wrote from memory)

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private int extern MessageBox(windowhandle, message, caption, flag);
public static void MessageBox(windowhandle, string message, string caption)
{
    MessageBox(windowhandle, message,caption, MB_TOPMOST);
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To show the MessageBox on top-most of all for the application

**Code**

```
//Should be MessageBox.Show() below
MessageBox.Show(this, "My top most message");
```

**Reason for not being `MB_TOPMOST` by default**

> If MB_TOPMOST will be default then the `MessageBox` will show up in a 'system modal' mode and it will be exactly on top on that form and side effects are that the 'system modal' mode will cause the `MessageBox` to *Block* the windows until the message is dismissed normally it will be 'application modal' mode.

**Reference links**

1. [MSDN forum - How to display a MessageBox as topmost window](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7a515f66-8818-4ec5-9213-7ee479f8fb18/)
2. [SO - C# MessageBox To Front When App is Minimized To Tray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834954/468718)

Comment: This answer looks great! but I thought messageboxes blocked the windows anyway?

Comment: From the [msdn forum mentioned in the answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7a515f66-8818-4ec5-9213-7ee479f8fb18/) I found that there is something like `system modal` and `application modal`. May be I'll check for more details later on this..

Comment: Only modal message boxes bock their forms, the 'regular' one can still persist even after you exited out of the program that spawned it.

Comment: I believe that msdn page is where I got the idea from for my eventual solution, I think the point about system modal vs application modal is exactly what I was looking for thanks :D (will accept soon)

Comment: As an additional note, imagine if the default were for MessageBoxs to be topmost: You are working in Application A, with Application B in the background running some operation. While you are working, Application B throws a MessageBox, which being topmost, appears over the top of Application A. Without any context, at best you might be confused, at worst, you could interpret the message in the context of Application A and click the wrong option, causing some unintended action in Application B.

Answer (score 94):

The proposed solutions work if you can get a handle or reference to the window the dialog is supposed to appear on top of. However, this may not always be possible or easy to achieve:

- the window is a splash screen and should not tightly coupled with your business logic
- the window is created by another class or library than the current one
- the window is out of your control, i.e. from a third party (native) library

In such scenarios, you *could* use the Win232 `MessageBox` API from `User32.dll`, but a simpler, managed solution is also available:

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "Hello, I'm on top!");
```

The code `new Form { TopMost = true }` will create a hidden form with the `MB_TOPMOST` property, which is inherited by the messagebox dialog window. As a result, it will appear on top of all your other windows. Using `new Form()` inline has no side-effects, has no visual appearance and it will be destroyed normally via the garbage collector.

*Note: if you are not inside a form already, don't forget the namespace, this is `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`, not `System.Windows.MessageBox`! (thanks, [user1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105097/why-isnt-messagebox-topmost/23723931#comment46178269_23723931)).*

Comment: Interesting approach, the answer chosen is done so because of the difference between application modal and system modal. Your approach I assume would still keep the messagebox application modal and would be useful in the circumstances you have outlined. +1

Comment: @Sayse: indeed, it keeps the messagebox application modal. We use it a lot in business logic library methods that are allowed to open a messagebox, but it is just to cumbersome to always have to pass the current form as a parameter.

Comment: Just to clarify for others this is `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` not `System.Windows.MessageBox`

Comment: This is the only solution that solved my problem. Thanks Abel!

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution, also for those who are getting "Cross thread Exception" using "this" should use "new Form { TopMost = true }".

Comment: I found this while making an Excel AddIn, and for anyone in a similar situation where the `MessageBox` isn't popping up in front, adding `Application.DoEvents();` before calling `MessageBox.Show()` fixed the problem for me. This answer also worked, *but* on multimonitor setups it would create the message box on the 1st monitor instead of the monitor that the Excel window is in.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "Hello, I'm on top!", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);` - best for me!!

Comment: For WPF it will be MessageBox.Show(new Window(){ TopMost = true }, "Hello, I'm on top!");

Comment: In my case the problem was with MessageBox's display before the main window was shown. I took to the trick of starting the still hidden main window with TopMost = true, using MessageBox::Show(this, "message"), this referring to the main window, getting the Shown message of the main window and resetting TopMost there to false again. (C++ CLI)

Comment: @PawełIwaneczko was close: `new System.Windows.Window() { Topmost = true },` - no capital `M`

Comment: I used messagebox in a class (without form) and it worked . thanks.

Answer (score 7):

When showing `MessageBox` provide its owner as the first argument. For example when invoking from a `Form` instance call:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "Message");
```

Provide a reference to the window owning it as the first argument.

Message boxes (and modal forms in general) do *not* appear on top of all windows of your application. They only appear on top of their *owner*. If you want your message-box (or other modal forms) be on top of your splash screen, set their owner to the splash form instance.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.. how would this ensure a messagebox is always above all other windows? or what does this achieve?

Comment: It won't. It will always be on top of its owner only. If you want it to appear on top of splash screen set its owner to the splash screen instance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given above is obviously correct minus the fact that it needs to call System.iDisposable.Dispose on the object new Form.

```
MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
string message = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("MESSAGE");
string caption = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("TITLE");
DialogResult result;
Form form;
using (form = new Form())
{
    form.TopMost = true;
    result = MessageBox.Show(form, caption, message, buttons, icon);
}
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // do something with the result
}
```

For more:

[Top-Most-MessageBox Examples](https://gist.github.com/mikeyhalla/0c5f83225c5eb30cd75b92010b088dae#file-top-most-messagebox-cs)

Answer (score 3):

I try to paste a more complete code piece, it's definitely working

```
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MessageBox")]
    public static extern int MessageBoxUser32(int hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);

    const uint MB_TOPMOST = 0x00040000;
    const uint MB_OK  = 0x00000000;
    const uint MB_OKCANCEL = 0x00000001;
    const uint MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE = 0x00000002;
    const uint MB_YESNOCANCEL = 0x00000003;
    const uint MB_YESNO = 0x00000004;
    const uint MB_RETRYCANCEL = 0x00000005;

     public static void ShowMessageBox(string message, bool topMost = true
        , string title = null, MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    {
        if(topMost)
        {
            uint mbv = MB_TOPMOST;

            if (buttons == MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                mbv |= MB_OK;
            if (buttons == MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
                mbv |= MB_OKCANCEL;
            if (buttons == MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore)
                mbv |= MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE;
            if (buttons == MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
                mbv |= MB_YESNOCANCEL;
            if (buttons == MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                mbv |= MB_YESNO;
            if (buttons == MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)
                mbv |= MB_RETRYCANCEL;

            MessageBoxUser32(0, message, title == null ? string.Empty : title, MB_TOPMOST);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message, title == null ? string.Empty : title, buttons);
        }
    }
```