# MessageBox Bring to front in WPF tray icon app

Tags: c#, wpf

My app is in the tray icon and I want a messagebox to first appear on front but not stay on top.

If I click another window the messagebox should not stay on top.

Also I want to open several message boxes at the same time, so when the user overs the mouse on the taskbar they can see a preview of all the message boxes. This works with default messagebox but I can't bring it to front when it first appears.

I tried the win32 api with all the modes and also making new forms but nothing works for all the requirements...

[C# MessageBox To Front When App is Minimized To Tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834819)

Comment: have you tried using any of the following options on a default messagebox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220882/keep-messagebox-show-on-top-of-other-application-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Chris I tried all those but they make it always on top it cannot be hidden by the user by clicking another window or minimized.

Comment: using topmost on the form should give you what you require, but maybe giving an example of your form would help someone to answer

Comment: with topmost it is always on top or does it go to background for you by clicking another window?